# Using createElement to write file to downloads folder fails in Phonegap Android app

Tags: file, download, save

I've used the following javascript code to create and save a file in the downloads folder. This works fine in Chrome, but the same code fails when compiled to an Android app via phonegap. How do I get this to work? At one point it worked but only intermittently, and then stopped working altogether. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
filename ='info.xml';  
XMLtext = 'blah';  
alert(XMLtext);  

//Create download file 
var element = document.createElement('a');  
element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(XMLtext));  
element.setAttribute('download', filename);  
element.style.display = 'none';  
document.body.appendChild(element);  
element.click();  
document.body.removeChild(element);
```